# How to drag and drop cards in scrollview using react-native

Tags: drag-and-drop, react-native, scrollview

Friends,
I was given a task of dragging and dropping Views (Cards) in react-native. The Views are added to the scroll view and the idea is that when you drag a View all the other views should takes its place just like the icons moves in the iOS when you drag and move icons.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far. Can you show us your code.

Comment: I don't know where to start, I am thinking implementing drag and drop views in scrollview and repeatedly sort the items in scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

This question is to broad to answer here. In summary, you should check out the documentation for `Animated`. 
This blog post is not a specific solution to your problem, but it explains the basics of this API: http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-animated-api-with-panresponder/